# How do you call that element on a mobile website / app

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, responsive

I try to build something like this element from Google Maps with HTML/CSS/JS [image: Google Maps Example]

For research i tried to find examples how others solved this in HTML but couldn't find anything. So im guessing I'm just looking for the wrong buzzwords.

I tried 'drawer', 'draggable content' 'content above fixed background' and so on... So I'm looking for hints, examples or best practices to achieve this as smooth as possible for mobile devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just give the image `position: fixed` and a `z-index: 1` and then just have the rest of the content have `z-index: 2` so it covers the map when you scroll down?

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: right now that would be my preferred solution. I wasn't quite sure because in my case i have a more complex object where the image / map is.

but originally i was searching for a term for that. how would you call that pattern?

Comment: I guess parallax? Google a bit about parallax and see if it is what you need.

Comment: i guess in the end it's some kind of parallax @bojan-ivanac

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally stumbled upon the name for this element.

In googles material design it's called "bottom sheet"

see https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-sheets.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm searching for the same element and behaviour like in the mobile version on google maps.

This is the closest  to the google maps behaviour I could find. Dragging it out and be able to scroll if there is more content.

https://mui.wertarbyte.com/#!/ExpandableBottomSheet/3

The CSS part is `margin-top: 50vh` for the sheet and I guess some JS for the drag/scroll behaviour.

Unfortunately, with this approach, the map underneath is not accessible anymore, even if the sheet is just covering half of the screen.

Comment: Position fixed should solve the problem without any js hassle 

Comment: But then you can't scroll the sheet anymore, right?

Comment: Yes you can scroll as if there was no tomorrow. I made a pen for you: https://codepen.io/denns/pen/qpJoda

Comment: instead of margin-top you can set `position : relative` and `top: 50vh`. I don't like this approach, but it will work.

Comment: Wow, that was easy. I guess I was so impressed by the mobile google maps site, that I expected something more!* Thanks for sharing!